# Quiet output from write(chunk)

Tags: python, python-requests

Working in the Python interpreter, the following code works ... but with a console output of:
2048
2048
...
2048
2048

Is there anyway to run the fd.write(chunk) statement in a 'quiet' mode - i.e. no output to the console?

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('output.jpg', 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(2048):   
        fd.write(chunk)
```

Where url is a link to a jpg file and output.jpg is my saved file.

Thanks.

Comment: There should be no output

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Note he is talking about on the Python Interpreter (he's just getting the default print of the return value)

Answer (score 2):

The Python interpreter prints the return value of functions by default. Write returns the number of bytes it writes. If you don't want to see that, just store it in a variable which you never print, e.g.:

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('output.jpg', 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(2048):
        bytes = fd.write(chunk)
```

Comment: But isn't `.write()` a method, not a function?

Comment: Also, why does `write` prints to the screen and `writelines` doesn't? Thanks

Comment: @Confounded There's no salient difference between methods and functions in this case. A method is a special case of a function, which returns a value. If the printing to the screen you mention is in the same context as the OP, which is to say in an interpreter, it happens because `writelines` returns nothing (None), and the interpreter is smart enough not to print that.